# Fieldset disabled property not working if input is enclosed by div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap's disabled property on fieldset is supposed to disable all inputs under that fieldset tag.
It works perfectly if input tags are right after fieldset tag or after legend tag. As soon as I insert div tag between fieldset and input then disabled property is not working.

It works for following declaration...

```
<form id="form">
    <fieldset id="fieldset">
    <legend>User Details</legend>
            <input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" type="text"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

But not If I add input inside div tag

```
<form id="form">
    <fieldset id="fieldset">
    <legend>User Details</legend>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" type="text"/>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Can anyone please suggest how to get around this problem?

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/PGTw3/ Are you using the right css?

Comment: I was trying to disable fields using jQuery and used following syntax 
$("#fieldset").children().prop("disabled", true);
Where I should be disabling fieldset itself by
$("#fieldset").prop("disabled", true);

Comment: Yes Thats what you should have done. and thats what you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, `disabled` isn't a property of bootstrap; it is native html.

Second, it appears to work just fine. Are you perhaps using incompatible versions of jQuery/bootstrap?

```
<form id="form">
    <fieldset id="fieldset" disabled>
    <legend>User Details</legend>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" type="text"/>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/LAk6L/

Comment: Yes, fieldset is indeed HTML property; read on bootstrap docs hence thought it might be bootstrap thing.
I have tried several combination before posting this question. You just tried disabled in html tag, there it works even if input is inside div. However if you try to toggle this property using javascript then it does not work. I don't understand how it may conflict with jQuery/bootstrap as same thing works if I take input tag outside div tag.
Please take a look [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LAk6L/8/)

Comment: It does actually - see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/remus/LAk6L/ Be aware though that the disabling syntax changed from jQuery 1.5 to 1.6, so perhaps you're using an incorrect syntax. You didn't provide that code though.

Comment: I did provide code in my previous comment, see hyperlink on link, was not aware about exact how comment works in StackOverflow; now I know.
Here is more readable link
[http://jsfiddle.net/LAk6L/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/LAk6L/8/)
By the way I figured out what mistake I was making, I was using .children() method to set disabled on where I should just disable the fieldset. Missed this may be because I was stressing out other things. Thank you r3mus, your code helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$("#fieldeset").children().attr("disabled", "disabled");
```